# jQuery on mouse move target selects all similar elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-position, onmousemove

I have (for example) 6 elements, all with same classes and different content. All of them also have backgrounds that are slightly zoomed in. I need their backgrounds to move accordingly when the mouse hovers on them. My problem - all backgrounds move once I hover on a single element. Any help?
Here's my code:

HTML (of a single element):

```
<a href="/" class="project" style="background-image: url('link_to_image');"><p>Project</p><span>Description</span></a>
```

CSS (again, single element):

```
.project {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background: #b0bec5;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0rem 0px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 0px -50px 100px -40px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    white-space: initial;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.project p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 2%;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "Josefin Slab";
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all .46s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: .02s;
    z-index: 1;
}

.project span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 2%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    transition: all .46s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: .02s;
    z-index: 1;
}

.project:hover p {
    bottom: 88%;
}

.project:hover span {
    top: 15%;
}

.project:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px -30rem 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

JS:

```
$(".project").on("mousemove", function(e){
    x = (e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft * 1.5) / 4;
    console.log(x);
    $(".project").css('background-position-x', x + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Read through this page on event basics: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: It works fine here: [Demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/90djfyb7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this`!

```
$(".project").on("mousemove", function(e){
    x = (e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft * 1.5) / 4;
    console.log(x);
    $(this).css('background-position-x', x + 'px'); //"this" refers to the .project elem that the event is occurring on.
});
```

Comment: To avoid strange issues with scoping, it is recommended to not use "this", but to instead use "e.currentTarget".

Comment: @lostPixels -- Where does it say that?

Comment: "$(this)" when you used this here.

Comment: @lostPixels _"it is recommended"_ - by whom?